# Изменить значок одной (первой) вершины многоугольника

Tags: yandex-maps-api, polygon

Для редактора многоугольника требуется сделать удобный интерфейс завершения редактирования без поп-ап меню на многоугольнике. Для этого (на нескольких сайтах видел) используется клик по первой точке многоугольника, которую, соответственно нужно выделять от всех остальных, например, значком в виде галочки.
Вопрос в том, можно ли изменить дизайн одной выбранной точки многоугольника (хотя бы в режиме редактирования), и как это сделать?
В принципе есть обходной путь создавать в начале рисования многоугольника метку, совпадающую координатами с первой точкой, и вешать на событие drag метки перенос соответствующей вершины многоугольника, но это не очень подходит.

Comment: "Для этого (на нескольких сайтах видел) используется клик по первой точке многоугольника, которую, соответственно нужно выделять от всех остальных, например, значком в виде галочки." А есть пример такого сайта? Тогда можно посмотреть как это устроено у них.

Comment: Например cian.ru фильтр по области на карте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дизайн одной точки редактора меняется так:

```
myPolyline.editor.getView().then((e) => {
    e.getVertexPlacemarks().get(0).options.set({
        ...
    });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/euyk3Lw2/

Comment: Спасибо за направление, однако, пока не получается. У вас в примере линия, точки которой уже заданы на момент вызова getView(). У меня же пользователь начинает рисовать полигон с первой точки, соответственно getView() уже отработал до момента начала рисования. Пытался так: myPolygon.editor.events.add(['vertexadd'], function(e){
e.getVertexPlacemarks().get(0).get(0).options.set({ - это не сработало. Не могу даже понять для какого объекта нужно вызывать getVertexPlacemarks() для полигона. По документации вроде так myPolygon.editor.getVertexPlacemarks(), но не работает.

Comment: Это не итоговый код конечно, но думаю направление мысли должно быть понятно https://jsfiddle.net/tp46bkhn/

Comment: В IE этот код не работает, т.к. промисы не поддерживаются. Даже подключение bluebird проблему не решило. :( А можно ли как-то попроще? Извините за нахальство, но нужно работающее везде решение. Не нашел ни одного примера, где используется getVertexPlacemarks(), и документация ничего не объясняет. :(

Comment: в каком ИЕ не работает?

Comment: Неправильно определили проблему. Я использовал стрелочную функцию https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions и поэтому не работало. Замените её просто на "function(e){"

Comment: Спасибо вам, добрый человек, за подарок на мой ДР! Наконец заработало! :)